# Powershell script how to silent supply values for the following parameter?

Tags: windows, powershell, script

I have this script copying first month backup file from directory to another.
This works fine but needs user intervention and not execute automatically. How i can silent this message ?

[image: Screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
$bak_path = "C:\Users\admin\Pictures\test"
$backup_dest = "C:\Users\admin\Pictures\paste"
get-childitem -path $bak_path -Filter "*" | 
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }  | 
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
    select-object -last 1 | 
    copy-item -Destination (join-path $backup_dest )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is [`join-path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6). You need to supply a path and a child path. So by doing that you would get rid of the prompt. It's unclear why that `join-path` is there in the first place. It's likely that you could just leave it out.

Answer (score 2):

This message comes from `join-path`, since `join-path` needs a `-Path` and a `-ChildPath` to work.

so your command should look like this `join-path -path $backup_dest -childpath xy`

but in my opinion, you don't need `join-path` at all.

why not just `copy-item -Destination $backup_dest`?

which paths do you want to join?